# Empty String to indicate object state

Tags: java, string, state

From time to time I bump into code like this:

```
...
private final JButton addButton = new JButton(...);
private String warningMsg = "";

private void update(){
    addButton.setEnabled(warningMsg != null && warningMsg.isEmpty());
}
...
```

As you can see, `warningMsg` possibly holds a warning message. When no message is needed, it will hold the empty string `""`/ Based on this behavior, a button gets enabled or disabled.

There are 2 things that are bothering me. First, why not set `warningMsg` to `null` if the string is not needed? I consider `null` a better choice, as an empty string is still a valid string to me. An outsider cannot know he has to check for emptiness, but if the string is null, that is something he can see. Second, behavior is based on the content of a string, which is in my opinion, poor coding.

The question is mainly about the first issue. Do you consider an empty string a good choice to indicate "nothing", which is infact a specific object state?

Comment: `Empty String` prevents NPEs.

Comment: This is a matter of convention. I would consider `null` a better option (in this case an empty error does also mean no error). Personally I'd add a boolean flag hasError along the message itself.

Comment: `warningMsg` is for *display*. You always want to display *something*, even if that something is "nothing". Using display strings as keepers of object state is a poor choice. Keep that where it belongs: in the model.

Comment: @TheLostMind Sometimes a null return value is justified. To prevent NPE's, I think people should fall back on the failing early principle, define external object mutation carefully, and define the contract. Mostly some default is OK. In this case, an empty String is no good default I guess, because an empty warning message means nothing to the user.

Comment: So does an NPE @Timmos :D

Comment: @Timmos - I'd rather see the application *running* than crash stating NPE at *LineWhereYouHaveForgottenANullCheck*.

Answer (score 1):

> The question is mainly about the first issue. Do you consider an empty string a good choice to indicate "nothing", which is infact a specific object state?

An empty String is a perfect choice to *display* nothing. You just can throw it into your GUI without needing to null-check it every time.

But: A display string is a poor choice for holding object state. You should have some kind of datamodel holding the state of if there has been a warning or not. And that should be (the only) source for the "enabled"-state of your control.
This is also clearer to "Outsiders" as you call them.

`boolean DataModel.hasWarning()` - something like that...